# Slow performance on Android tablet with SurfaceView

Tags: performance, surfaceview, android

I'm developing a card game in Android using SurfaceView and canvas to draw the UI.

I've tried to optimize everything as much as possible but I still have two questions:

- During the game I'll need to draw 40 bitmaps (the 40 cards in the italian deck), is it better to create all the bitmaps on the onCreate method of my customized SurfaceView (storing them in an array), or create them as needed (every time the user get a new card for example)?
- I'm able to get over 90 fps on an old Samsung I5500 (528 MHz, with a QVGA screen), 60 fps on  an Optimus Life (800 MHz and HVGA screen) and 60 fps with a Nexus One/Motorola Razr (1 GHz and dual core 1GHz with WVGA and qHD screens) but when I run the game on an Android tablet (Motorola Xoom dual core 1 GHz and 1 GB of Ram) I get only 30/40 fps... how is that possible that a 528 MHz cpu with 256 MB of RAM can handle 90+ fps and a dual core processor can't handle 60 fps? I'm not seeing any kind of GC calling at runtime....

EDIT: Just to clarify I've tried both ARGB_888 and RGB_565 without any changes in the performance...

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some points for you to consider:

1. It is recommended not to create new objects while your game is running, otherwise, you may get unexpected garbage collections.
2. Your FPS numbers doesn't sound good, you may have measurement errors, However my guess is that you are resizing the images to fit the screen size and that affects the memory usage of your game and may cause slow rendering times on tablets.
3. You can use profiling tools to confirm: [TraceView](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html)
4. OpenGL would be much faster
5. last tip: don't draw overlapping cards if you can, draw only the visible ones.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

1. Ok so it's better to create the bitmap in the onCreate method, that is what I'm doing right now...
2. They are ok, I believe that the 60 fps on some devices are just some restrictions made by producers since you won't find any advantage in getting more than 60 fps (I'm making this assumption since it doesn't change rendering 1 card, 10 cards or no card... the OnDraw method is called 60 times per second, but if I add for example 50/100 cards it drops accordingly)  I don't resize any card cause I use the proper folder (mdpi, hdpi, ecc) for each device, and I get the exact size of the image, without resizing it...
3. I've tried to look at it but from what I understand all the time of the app execution is used to draw the bitmap, not to resize or update its position here it is:

[image]

4. I know, but it would add complexity to the developing and I believe that using a canvas for 7 cards on the screen should be just fine….
5. I don't draw every card of the deck.. I just swap bitmap as needed :)

UPDATE: I've tried to run the game on a Xoom 2, Galaxy Tab 7 plus and Asus Transformer Prime and it runs just fine with 60 fps…. could it be just a problem of Tegra 2 devices?